# systemd service failing with git commands

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to switch from `cron` to `systemd` for a pretty simple thing. I have a small bash script `sync_org_git` which basically cd-s into a specific folder, does some git manipulations. The git commands write some things to `stdout` (untracked files, feedback after commit etc) which is nothing out of the ordinary for git, but `systemctl --user start sync-org-git.timer` says job failed. Do I need to modify my script or the systemd files?

Here's the service and timer file:

```
❯ cat sync-org-git.service
[Unit]
Description=sync org to git


[Service]
ExecStart=/home/fbence/bin/sync_org_git

❯ cat sync-org-git.timer
[Unit]
Description=Sync org git timer
Requires=sync-org-git.service

[Timer]
OnBootSec=0min
OnCalendar=*:*:0/5
Unit=sync_org_git.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**UPDATE**

Using `ExecStart=-/home/fbence/bin/sync_org_git`

results in
`sync-org-git.timer: Refusing to start, unit sync_org_git.service to trigger not loaded.`

but I actually see the output of the shell script in the journal.

Comment: Do you always do a `systemctl --user daemon-reload` after editing the unit files?

Comment: yes (this is just to have a long enough comment)

Comment: You are using underlines in `Unit=` but the unit filename uses hyphens.

Comment: Wow, well that is embarrassing ... :D That was actually the problem ... The only mystery is then, how did output from the script still get triggered (or at least, why did I see it's output in the logs?).

Comment: Did you not have the `Unit=` line originally, as you don't need it anyway when the service has the same name (with .timer replaced by .service, of course).

Comment: Ah, yes, that is likely the cause ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your command exits with a non-zero return code, then systemd takes this as a failure to run. You can either ignore the return code by adding a `-` prefix as in `ExecStart=-/home/fbence/bin/sync_org_git`, or you can add an extra line listing what return codes mean ok, eg:

```
SuccessExitStatus=0 1 7
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem, that exit code of my script is 0. At least when I run it manually it is 0, and if I run it via systemctl the printed output seems to be exactly the same, so that's why I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: See the update with `-`.

Comment: Tbh, this was not exactly my problem, but it did help, and considering you solved my problem in a comment, I'm going to accept this answer.